# How to create statement for List<object>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, list

I have a code part with `List<object>` like that:

```
List<object> Result= new List<object>();
Some sql connection code...

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(@" Select TOP(10) a,b,c from table
```

Some sql connection code...

```
 while (rd.Read())
        {
           Result.Add(new
            {                  
               a=rd[0],
               b=rd[1],              
               c=rd[2]    
            });  
        }
        rd.Close();
        con.Close();
```

I want to add some statement for `Result` value. For example

```
if(a == "") 
a=5;
```

and i use `List<object>` in javascript part

```
var listCategory = $find("ace2").get_completionList();

          var count2 = listCategory .childNodes.length;
          for (j =0; j < count2; j++) {                
              var item2 = listCategory .childNodes[j]._value;
              var a= item2.a;
              var b= item2.b;
              var c= item2.c;
          }
```

and i use this value in html.

**How to add some statement for `List<object>()` value ?**

Comment: It's really not at all clear what you mean by "some statement" here.

Comment: Bip, I guess you should read this first ["Writing the perfect question" by Jon Skeet](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Comment: what you are asking is not clear. Anyway I would guess that your issue is that you populate a List of objects with anonymous classes and then try unsuccessfully to read a, b and c from elements in the list. You should use a named class (eg Result) with properties a,b and c instead and use a List of Result.

Answer (score 1):

Dont know how many columns  you are returning? if you do know create a holder class else you have to handle casting on your own and is less maintainable.

```
List<KnownType> Result= new List<KnownType>();
a=rd[0];
b=rd[1],
c=rd[2]  
if(a=="" or string.IsNullOrEmpty(a) or YourCondition)
{
change what ever values you want
}
Result.Add(new KnownType
            {                  
               a,b,c
            });
```

Comment: IsNullOrEmpty covers a=="" so you don't need both. Also `or` won't work you need either `|` or `||`

Answer (score 0):

If I right understood you want to make conditional intialization of a runtime type, *before* adding it to the list.

So you can create a function:

```
public object GetObject(SqlDataReader rd) {


    var aVal = rd[0]; 
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(aVal)) 
        aVal = "5"; //STRING, in your case it's a NUMBER

    return new
           {                  
              a=aVal,
              b=rd[1],              
              c=rd[2]    
           });  
}
```

and after use this in add:

```
while (rd.Read())
{
    ....
    Result.Add(GetObject(rd)); 
    .....
}
```

If this is not what you're asking for, please clarify.

Comment: why not just `{a=rd[0] == "" ? "5" : rd[0], b=..`

Comment: @ConradFrix: I just want *clearly* manifest what I say. How to write is up to the OP. Yes, it can be done, in this concrete case, without any function. But, as it's not clear to me, what OP is asking for *realy*, prefer more general (concept, if you wish) solution.